# Error using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript

From server side I call an aaa() javascript function using the fallowing code inside a button click event:

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bbb As String = "aaa();"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "123", bbb, False)
End Sub

The client code is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function aaa() 
    {
        alert("hola");
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button I receive the error message 'aaa' is undefined
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<script>` should be inside your `<head>` section, or at least before the part where you call `aaa()`.

Right now, you're defining `aaa()` AFTER it has initialized your button.

Comment: Perfect, I moved the script and it is working. Thanks

Comment: Remember to mark your answer (and upvote anything helpful)!  Of course, you can always wait for a better answer but if you've received your preferred answer, make sure to mark it :)